# MySQL: How to insert character "@"

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

The collation of the table where I want to insert the "@" character is latin_spanish_ci and if I execute "show variables like 'char%'" I've got these ...

```
Variable_name   Value
character_set_client    utf8
character_set_connection    utf8
character_set_database  latin1
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results   utf8
character_set_server    latin1
character_set_system    utf8
character_sets_dir  /usr/share/mysql/charsets/
```

How can I execute:

```
INSERT INTO `tbl002_club` (`id`, `name`, `web`, `twitter`) VALUES (1,'C.B. AL-QAZERES','http://cbal-qazeres.blogspot.com/', '‎@CBALQAZERES')
```

And not get this error ...

> Error Code: 1366. Incorrect string value: '\xE2\x80\x8E@CB...' for
>   column 'twitter' at row 1

**Edit I:**

The statement with I create the table:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `tbl002_club`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tbl002_club` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl002_club` (
  `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `twitter` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `web` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1
COLLATE = latin1_spanish_ci;
```

I have to say that I'm using mysql-workbench to execute all the querys.

Comment: Is that really the real query? If the input starts with an `@`, why should the error message give something else in front?

Comment: Yes is the real query. If I remove the twitter field the query works fine but If I add the twitter field I've got the error.

Comment: It's working fine for me...
**http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/558b38**

Comment: Provide us your table create statement.

Comment: Yes!!! I have added the table create statement to my initial post

Comment: `\xE2\x80\x8E` probably means you're having some funky characters present before the `@` character.

Comment: Thank you Terry for your answer but there is no funky chars before @ character. If you check the query before @ character there is nothing.

Comment: @Terry you are right mate that is the problem. Cheers

Comment: Yes @Peter Darmis, Terry is right!!!. Thank you for your help!!!

Answer (score 2):

Please check this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/336323). The unicode character [\u200e](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200e/index.htm) is in front of the `@` character and creates the problem in the query below.

```
INSERT INTO `tbl002_club` (`id`, `name`, `web`, `twitter`) VALUES (1,'C.B. AL-QAZERES','http://cbal-qazeres.blogspot.com/', '‎@CBALQAZERES')
```

Comment: Good spotting... `+1`

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala thanks, glad i could help. I practically learned a lot of stuff from this website (and others) so i am really satisfied i could help.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author)*.

I fixed it.

I have checked in sqlfiddle that my initial query has a "funky" char before "@". Chat that I can't see. So, I have delete "@" and rewrite again and it works. I've got more queries to insert more rows and these other queries works fine. I don't know what happened!